# java.util.Date format output changes when migrating from hibernate-4 to hibernate-5

Tags: migration, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x, java.util.date, mysql-5.5

I am currently trying to update some of our current libraries, and I've hit a blocking issue. This is a legacy application, here's the basic setup:

```
Java 8
Tomcat 7
Mysql 5.5.27-28.1-log Percona Server
Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE
```

The Relevant Hibernate versions are here:

```
55:HIBERNATE_VERSION = "4.3.11.Final"
236:                "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:#{HIBERNATE_VERSION}",
239:                "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:#{HIBERNATE_VERSION}",
241:                "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:#{HIBERNATE_VERSION}",
```

The updated version is:

`HIBERNATE_VERSION = "5.2.12.Final"`

I'll spare you the details, but there are quite a few other dependencies. I gradually eliminated every other change (including the related spring update), but the above listed libraries are the only 3 that are changing.

Now, one of the front-end clients are choking because the date format had changed.

Under hibernate-4, it looks like:

> createdDate: "2014-09-15",

With the above changes, it now looks like this:

> createdDate: 1410753600000,

The class annotations look like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(columnDefinition="datetime")
private Date createdDate;
```

The table schema is on mysql and its listed as this:

> | createdDate      | datetime      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |

Where "Date" is a java.util.Date. Yes, I understand java.util.Date is horrible. I also know that @Temporal was lagging behind java 8 and the new features. We use jodatime and will be looking to standardize on the new J8 conventions, but this is an old application and this is a central table on an even older database.

I've tried a number of solutions including:

- consolidating dependencies
- isolating dependencies (where we are now)
- implementing a @Converter globally (breaks other specific date formats)
- using said @Converter on only the field (still getting epoch time)
- using the outputting json mapper to set the field (breaks because every time/date ends up having that format)
- converting the base type to java.sql.Date (as that's what Temporal did).

From checking the change logs, I can't find anything that would explain this particular change, let alone any reason default behavior would change so drastically. I understand that a larger migration can help, but I'm really just looking to use the old default behavior so I can straighten out the rest of my upgrades without having them wrapped up in major code/db changes.

Any ideas here? I've upgraded hibernate many times before and never encountered a problem quite like this.

Comment: FYI, Hibernate [apparent supports *java.time* classes](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844) that supplant the troublesome legacy date-time classes such as `Date`.

Comment: I understand that, and I like I said in the question we already were using jodatime extensively and are evaluating a move for those to get into java.time. This is a legacy class and I'm trying to do an upgrade without a lot of code wrapped in a dependency change. We have similar @Temporal mappings in the codebase, but the app is large enough that consolidating every date field is going to have more issues than just trying to figure out why this particular behavior changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was still `@Temporal` not being honored between Hibernate-5 and JPA 2.2, so the mapping disappeared. I had a faux DTO returning the data and forced a formatter on that particular field, which seems to have fixed the issue.